# How to view full details (like a token) of context

Tags: kubernetes

I created a context in Kubernetes with:

```
kubectl config set-context --token="<JWY_token>" myservice-context
```

When I run:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

I see all the contexts:

```
CURRENT   NAME                                                      CLUSTER                                     AUTHINFO                                           NAMESPACE
*         minikube                                                  minikube                                    minikube                                           
          myservice-context
```

I want to see more details about `myservice-context`. For example, I want to see the token I just pass it while creating it.
I tried to run `get-context` with the name of my service but it doesn't provide the full details:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts myservice-context
CURRENT   NAME                 CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
          myservice-context
```

How can I see the **full** details of the context (such as the token) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl config view` will show you, though it hides some fields (like the very long embedded TLS certificates).

If that's not enough information, by default the data is stored in a single YAML file, on Linux/MacOS in `~/.kube/config`, and you can open that up in a text editor.

Comment: It seems like the solution but when run it: `cat ~/.kube/config` I see the context but not the token I added with `--token=<JWY_token>`...

Comment: `~/.kube/config` is the authoritative source of information, so if it's not there, it's not there.

Looking at the official documentation, I think you might want [kubectl config set-credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-set-credentials-em-) instead.

Comment: It also turn out that, according to @liggitt (Jordan Liggitt), that `set-context` doesn't do anything with `--token` so I probably used in the wrong place.

Comment: to show `REDACTED` fields in `kubectl config view` you can use `--show-all` argument. To manipulate tokens you can use `kubeadm token list` and `kubeadm token create` respectively.